# Positioning text inside OptionMenu in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-menu, ttkwidgets

hy I am working on tkinter python project.

I am trying to position text to the Left inside OptionMenu using anchor option but it does not seem to work. I am using ttk theme widgets.

[image]

Here is the code that I am trying currently.

```py
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('my.TMenubutton', font=("Cambria", fontSize, "bold"), background="white", anchor = W  )
shapeMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(shapeFrame, shape, myShapes[1], *myShapes, style='my.TMenubutton', command=getShapes)
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no anchor option under `TMenubutton`. I tried `TLabel`, and it worked. Don't know if there is any side effect though.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x100')
CHART_TYPES = ('Reticle', 'Circle Grid', 'Checkerboard', 'Grille', 'Slanted Edge MTF')

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('my.TLabel', font=("Cambria", 10, "bold"), background="white", anchor = 'w'  )

chart_type = tk.StringVar()
chart_type.set(CHART_TYPES[0])
# chart_selector = tk.OptionMenu(root, chart_type, *CHART_TYPES)
chart_selector = ttk.OptionMenu(root, chart_type, *CHART_TYPES, style='my.TLabel')
# chart_selector.configure(anchor='w')
chart_selector.pack(expand=True, fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```